# How many data can be mass data? How many dimensions can be high-dimension?

Tags: data-mining

i'm going to be a master now, and my teacher's research direction is data-mining for high-dimension mass data.

but i still can't imagine what are mass data, and how many dimension can be called high-dimension.

tks~

Answer (score 1):

Mass data? Well, you can consider that all Google's requests, considered as a stream, contitute a mass data.

Mass dimensions? Imagine a Google engineer considering a few topics like "five-legged dogs". He can think that every user represents a dimension, and compute some correlation stuff. And there i **a lot** of users.

---

Now, back to the point, there are no clear definitions of mass data, or of high dimensions. However, you can consider that :

- If you have so much data that you cannot load all of it in memory (I'm talking about HDD, not just RAM), it's mass data
- If your algorithms begin to fail because of the curse of dimensionality, it's high dimensionality. 1.000.000 dimensions is surely high-dimension. You can often consider that 1.000 is high dimension too.